# Xcode analyzer is showing leak for CGPathRef when it's in a class instance method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgpath, clang-static-analyzer

I have a class `GraphicView` that basically creates a `UIView` that uses a `CAShapeLayer` as  its default `layer` object:

**GraphicView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GraphicView : UIView
{
    CAShapeLayer *_shapeLayer;
}
@property(nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer;

- (void) loadPath:(CGPathRef)path;

@end
```

**GraphicView.m**

```
#import "GraphicView.h"

@implementation GraphicView

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self.shapeLayer = (CAShapeLayer *) self.layer;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [CAShapeLayer class];
}

- (void) loadPath:(CGPathRef)path
{
    CGMutablePathRef tempPath = path;
    self.shapeLayer.path = tempPath;
    CGPathRelease(tempPath);
}

@end
```

When I call `loadPath`:

**GraphicViewController.m**

```
- (void) loadSquarePath
{
    [self.graphicView loadPath:[SquarePath newSquarePath]];
}
```

**SquareBalloonPath.m**

```
- (CGMutablePathRef) newSquareBalloonPath
{
    CGSize mutablePathInitialSize = [self squareBalloonPathInitialSize];
    CGMutablePathRef mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(mutablePath, NULL, 0, 0);
    CGPathAddRect(mutablePath, NULL, CGRectMake(0, 0, mutablePathInitialSize.width, mutablePathInitialSize.height));
    CGPathCloseSubpath(mutablePath);
    return mutablePath;
}
```

I get an analyzer error saying "Potential leak of an object of type 'CGMutablePathRef'". However, when I move `loadPath` from `GraphicView` to `GraphicViewController` (and change the method header to `loadGraphicView:WithPath:`

**GraphicViewController.m**

```
- (void) loadGraphicView:(GraphicView *)graphicView withPath:(CGPathRef)path
{
    CGPathRef tempPath = path;
    graphicView.shapeLayer.path = tempPath;
    CGPathRelease(tempPath);
}

- (void) loadSquarePath
{
    [self.graphicView loadPath:[SquarePath newSquarePath]];
}
```

The analyzer error goes away! Is there something I have to tell the compiler so I can get `loadPath` to work when it's included as an instance method within `GraphicView`?

Comment: Since `loadGraphicView` takes a GraphicView as a parameter, why isn't it an _instance_ property of GraphicView (that _doesn't_ take a GraphicView as a parameter)? Just call it `-(void) loadWithPath:`.

Comment: @matt yeah you're right, got so wound up in redesigning some of my code and moving stuff around that I lost sight of it. going to change it and see if it fixes it, though if it does not sure I understand why.

Comment: I also question why you call `CGPathRelease` inside either `loadGraphicView` method. Neither version should assume that the passed in path needs to be released. You are likely to overrelease `path` in some cases. Also, why does `loadGraphicView` take a `CGMutablePathRef` instead of just `CGPathRef`?

Comment: @matt Fixed it and updated the question, still having same issue but code is nicer.

Comment: @HangarRash I have all my shape paths stored in one class and are returned as above using the new keyword i.e. newSquareBalloonPath, so it needs to be released in that case right because new will add one to the reference count. As for why mutable, I'm building the paths using CGPathAddCurveToPoint.

Comment: Yes, after calling `newSquarePath`, you do need to eventually call `CGReleasePath`. I'm just questioning the ownership and responsibility of that release. `loadPath` is not the owner of the created path so it shouldn't be the one that releases it. Ideally, the caller of `newSquarePath` should call `CGPathRelease`. And you should change `loadPath` to take `CGPathRef`, not `CGMutablePathRef`. `loadPath` does not need a mutable path.

Comment: @HangarRash Good idea, I will change CGMutablePathRef to CGPathRef. I agree about ownership, it was making my head explode a little when I started nesting method calls, passing the newSquarePath down the chain as opposed to working with it / releasing it in the initial method that gets it.

Comment: FYI - I created a project and added your two sets of code, first one, then the other. After adding enough other code to make it compile, I ran the analyzer. I get the message about the potential leak in both sets of code. I'm using Xcode 15.2 under macOS 14.3.1. Perhaps you need to post a minimal, complete example that replicates the issue. But in either case, the solution is as I stated earlier - the code that should call `CGPathRelease` is the code that calls `newSquarePath`. It makes the analyzer happy and it avoids the risk of over releasing.

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks for doing that. Dunno why I'm getting the analyzer error for one set of code and not the other, but regardless what you're saying about CGPathRelease and newSquarePath is correct. Have to find a new solution.

Comment: FWIW, I agree with HangarRash that whomever calls `newSquareBalloonPath` (or `newSquarePath`) should `CGPathRelease` it after calling `loadPath` (and that `loadPath` should not be releasing objects it did not create). For the sake of completeness, the other alternative is to use `UIBezierPath` instead of `CGPathRef`, which cuts the Gordian knot, because assuming you are using ARC, it completely eliminates the need to manually release the path.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the info, I'll definitely be using UIBezierPath for my next project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with ownership. You have one place that creates and takes ownership of the `CGMutablePathRef`. You then pass that reference to another method that then releases it. But that method should not take responsibility for releasing the reference. It has no idea if the reference it is getting should be released or not.

The simple fix is to put the responsibility in the correct place. Change `loadSquarePath` in `GraphicViewController` to something like this:

```objc
- (void) loadSquarePath
{
    CGMutablePathRef path = [SquarePath newSquareBalloonPath];
    [self.graphicView loadPath:path];
    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

and remove the call to `CGPathRelease` from `loadPath:` in `GraphicView`.

Or in the second set of code, remove `CGPathRelease` from `loadGraphicView:withPath:` in `GraphicViewController`.

These changes quiet the analyzer because it moves the responsibility of releasing to the same place that took the responsibility of ownership at creation.

This also eliminates possible crashes due to the `CGReleasePath` in `loadPath:` over-releasing paths that should not be released. While your current code is only passing a path reference that does need to be released, that may not always be the case.